# Why is my Auth0/passport authenticate call returning a false token, and how do I handle it?

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, jwt, auth0

I am implementing an auth0 login flow for a node js server that serves a react app. I have implemented the login and log out flows correctly, but in the `/callback` URL I am given a false token that cannot be decrypted.

So, if I visit `/login`, it takes me to the Auth0 form correctly; and I can log in successfully, according to the logs in Auth0. But when Auth0 redirects back to the callback url, I get a false token.

```
app.get("/callback", (request, response, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("auth0", (auth0Error, token) => {
    if (!token){
      // HERE, token is false
    }
    ...
  })(request, response, next);
});
```

What could cause this false token? How does the authenticate function work in a callback? And how should I handle this? Should I try auth0 again?

Answer (score 0):

To understand the issue, I started the project in debug mode and added some breakpoint. If you look carefully, `passport.authenticate()` method calls **Auth0Strategy** . Then, Auth0Strategy exchange code for token (Authorization Code flow) and returns user profile. Therefore, in the the callback route , token is not available. I added the following lines of code to access accessToken in the callback route.

```
const strategy = new Auth0Strategy(
  {
    domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
    clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: '/callback',

  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, done) {
    // accessToken is the token to call Auth0 API (not needed in the most cases)
    // extraParams.id_token has the JSON Web Token
    // profile has all the information from the user
    console.log(JSON.stringify(profile))
    console.log(accessToken);
    return done(null, profile, accessToken); // Passing access token 
  }
);
```

Then , callback route should have accessToken available.

```
router.get('/callback', function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('auth0', function (err, user, token) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      const returnTo = req.session.returnTo;
      delete req.session.returnTo;
      res.redirect(returnTo || '/user');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

This was added just to explain the flow. But you can ignore passing the token for production application.